# how to add partial hbs file inside master hbs file in sugarcrm

Tags: partial-views, sugarcrm, hbs

My goal is to show multiple pages like wizard inside a popup in sugarcrm . solution i seems is to added partial .hbs file inside master hbs file .

i have gone through documentation

https://support.sugarcrm.com/documentation/sugar_developer/sugar_developer_guide_12.2/user_interface/handlebars/

1. Create a Handlebars helper file

```
`(function(app) {
    app.events.on("app:init", function() {

        Handlebars.registerHelper("customUpperCase", function (text)
        {
            return text.toUpperCase();
        });

    });
})(SUGAR.App);`
```

2. create a JSGrouping extension

```
`foreach($js_groupings as $key => $groupings) {
    foreach($groupings as $file => $target) {
        if ($target == 'include/javascript/sugar_grp7.min.js') {
            //append the custom helper file
            $js_groupings[$key]['custom/JavaScript/my-handlebar-helpers.js'] = 'include/javascript/sugar_grp7.min.js';
        }

        break;
    }
}`
```

3. use your custom helpers in the HBS files by using:

```
`
  {{customUpperCase "MyString"}} `
```

But this is not working , and it only passing string in hbs file , i want to add full html or php page in hbs

i also tried iframe or include 'example.php' in hbs file , but it hangs in sugarcrm .
what is correct way to
add multiple child pages in one hbs file

Comment: I'm confused. You posted code for creating a helper. Helpers are *not* a way to insert partials. Helpers are custom handlebar functions. `partial` is an already existing handlebar helper that you can just call with `{{partial 'myPartial' this}}` and it will include other HBS(!) files, usually stored in the same folder ("myPartial.hbs" in this case).
Not sure how to use that in a wizard and if you're planning to exchange the entire content/templates on the fly. Maybe you could switch between parts of your .hbs using `{{#eq wizard_step 1}}...{{/eq}}`, `{{#eq wizard_step 2}}...{{/eq}}`, etc.

Comment: Oh right. Don't forget to call/trigger `render()` on the component if you want the hbs-Template to react to changes.

Comment: tnx , i was able to do this by {{partial 'myPartial' this}} . but I am not able to do this in a nested folder. i tried like {{partial 'PartialViews/WelcomeScreen' this}} . (folder structure is same) . but it is not accepted. please suggest

Comment: Try **without** specifying the folder in the partial call. E.g. if your file is `PartialViews/WelcomeScreen.hbs`, just use `{{partial 'WelcomeScreen' this}}`. I've done some tests and it seems *.hbs files in subfolders are loaded but their subfolder-path is not part of the resulting partial's name. Just the file name is.